# How do I get a value from a field with type array?

Tags: session, google-analytics, amazon-athena

I'm working with data from Google Analytics in AWS Athena, and I need to get the count of `session_id` values. However, the field's data type is an array. I was able to separate the events into rows, but I'm having trouble selecting the specific value. Here is my current query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT params.*, new_event_params.key
FROM "01_bronze_ga4".ga4_bigquery AS params
CROSS JOIN unnest(event_params) AS new_event_params (key)
WHERE 
    Substring(params."event_date", 1, 6) LIKE '2023%' AND 
    params.event_timestamp = 1673094862853604 AND 
    params.event_name = 'session_start'
```

The resulting table contains the necessary data; I just need help selecting the count of `session_id` values from within the array.  Here is the structure of the data:

{key=ga_session_id, value={string_value=null, int_value=1673094862, float_value=null, double_value=null}}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWdMR.png)

Comment: What is `session_id`? You query never mentions one. Can you please provide data structure and sample data with desired output?

Comment: The ga_session_id is inside the field  "event_params". I need to put in the "where" clausule only rows that contains the value of the ga_session_id.

Comment: What is result for `select typeof(event_params) from ga4_bigquery` ? And again - please share some sample data for more context.

Comment: I've just shared an image with the result of the querie. It returns one row for each parameter...

Comment: This helps but still please ad output of `select typeof(...)`